# Stop rails from looking for controller specific JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-assets

I'm using Rails 3.2 (old and unsupported, I know). It's a legacy application upgrade, and we didn't have controller specific `js/css` files previously, we have a different structure for them.

The problem is that the asset pipeline looks for `MyController.js` when I load `MyController` or worse: when I load a method it looks for a specific JS or CSS for that view.

Since I have this setting in `production.rb`: `config.assets.compile = false` it won't fall back to the asset pipeline if something isn't compiled. This causes errors like `device/passwords.js isn't precompiled` which is frustrating because I don't want/need a separate `js` file for this.

Rails 3.2 automatically requires these controller specificjs and , nothing in my code that does that that I know of and I've checked for this: `<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>` which also doesn't exist in my code.

I want it to stop doing that so that I don't have to arbitrarily create one `js` file for every action that I'm not going to use.

Is that possible in rails 3.2?

Comment: Post your application.html.erb layout as well as your application.js directory and your config/initializers/assets (that might be rails 4+ so also post) your config.application.rb file.

Comment: By default, rails 3.2 doesn't load assets by controller so it's probably an issue with the precompile request in your config if I had to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why rails was loading `controller#method` javascript and CSS is because of the line `<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>` which I had removed, but failed to reload my rails server - which was NGINX and I guess it was caching the previous results! It fixed it afterwards.